# How to git rm a file whose name starts with ':'

Tags: git

I've accidentally got a file in my repo named `:web,`. When typing `git rm :web,` it seems to think the colon is a part of a command and not the start of a filename:

```
fatal: pathspec 'web,' did not match any files
```

Quotes don't make a difference.

Comment: good question: what exactly is the meaning of an unescaped `git rm :web`?

Comment: @michas - did you read the documentation? 'A pathspec that begins with a colon `:` has special meaning. In the short form, the leading colon `:` is followed by zero or more "magic signature" letters (which optionally is terminated by another colon `:`), and the remainder is the pattern to match against the path. The optional colon that terminates the "magic signature" can be omitted if the pattern begins with a character that cannot be a "magic signature" and is not a colon.'

Comment: Does `git rm ./:web` work?

Comment: @KeithThompson, yes, that will work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `:` (and not just in your shell, but for `git` itself):

```
git rm '\:web,'
```

or

```
git rm \\:web,
```

Alternatively, you could use the `:`-based pathspec that the error is telling you about.  For example:

```
git rm :::web,
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative:

```
git rm ./:web
```

Prepending `./` to a name that refers to a file in the current directory makes it refer to the same file, but it doesn't have `:` as the first character. (This also works for file names starting with `-`.)

Note that this assumes that `git rm` only treats the `:` character specially if it occurs at the beginning of the file name. I think that's the case, but I haven't personally confirmed it.

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  The leading `:` makes `git` interpret the string as a pathspec rather than a simple filename.